# Avoiding deadlocks in bidirectional communication between goroutines

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine, channel

I am making my first experiences in Go, and so far I really like the goroutine and channels construct. I am wondering if there is an idiomatic way to avoid deadlocks in bidirectional communication between multiple goroutines. Consider the following example. There are three goroutines: *producer, worker* and *controller*.

- The producer produces integers. In reality this could be data coming
  from a network connection for example.
- The worker receives data from the producer and does some operation on
  it. Then, the worker directs the modified data to the controller.
- The controller sends a command to the worker in some cases. In the
  example this would happen if the received integer is bigger than 180.

The deadlock happens when the controller tries to send a command to the worker, while the worker tries to send an integer to the controller.

```
producerToWorker := make(chan int)
workerToController := make(chan int)
controllerToWorker := make(chan bool) // bool represents a command for this example

// Worker
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case i := <-producerToWorker:
            // Do some processing and send to controller
            workerToController <- (2 * i) + 1
        case <-controllerToWorker:
            // Would react to the command here
        }
    }
}()

// Controller
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case i := <-workerToController:
            fmt.Println(i)
            if i > 180 {
                // Send a command to the worker
                controllerToWorker <- true
            }
        }
    }
}()

// Producer
for {
    producerToWorker <- rand.Intn(100)
}
```

Example output:

```
163
175
95
113
1
189 // No deadlock
23
125
179
57
149
23
91
191 // No deadlock
133
95
175
177
181 // No deadlock
17
175
63
27
181 // Deadlock!
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Buffering the channels would make this deadlock more unlikely, but not solve it logically. I would like to avoid mutexes if possible. How do you handle such situations in Go?

**Edit**: To give a more real-world description: I came across this problem when I tried to implement a websocket client. The websocket client (*worker*) connects to an external service (*producer*) and receives messages from it (*producerToWorker*) and passes them to the controller (*workerToController*) to handle the received messages. The controller needs to react to the received messages, for example send a response or disconnect the client when an invalid message is received (*controllerToWorker*).

Comment: If it's sufficiently unlikely that this happens a lot, put the send to `controllerToWorker` into its own goroutine. If it happens a lot, so that you end up with enough goroutines to be a problem, redesign. Depending on the situation it may also be okay to simply discard some messages instead of blocking (which would be achieved with a default clause in a select statement).

Comment: This seems like a flawed design to me; your worker doesn't fully encapsulate its own logic (some of the logic is in the controller), and is receiving different messages from different sources for different reasons at the same time. A worker should be a black box, accepting work and handling it completely before moving on.

Comment: @Adrian I extended my question with my a description of my actual use case. How would you handle that situation?

Comment: If the producer service is external, then it's not communicating by channel, it's communicating by websocket, which is a completely different scenario. That said, if the worker needs two-way communication with the controller (which, from your description, seems to be the real worker in this scenario), it shouldn't be waiting on the producer and the controller equally; it should send its message to the controller and await the response before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

> [Is there ]an idiomatic way to avoid deadlocks in bidirectional communication between multiple goroutines?

No. Nothing "idiomatic" or based on a "pattern".

> How do you handle such situations in Go?

You redesign. Concurrent circular data flow is best avoided.